# Distinct value estimate of a population from distinct value counts of two halves of it

Tags: estimation, finite-population

A population $P$ is randomly divided into $A$ and $B$ (potentially differing in number of elements).

I know how many distinct values are in $A$ and how many are in $B$, as well as the number of total elements in each.

How do I estimate how many distinct values are in $P$?

Comment: If you want to do any better than the obvious bounds (the maximum and the sum), you will need more information or some assumptions about the distribution of $P.$

Comment: @whuber Really? Knowing nothing about the distribution of $P$, intuition says it's less likely to be the maximum or sum than some value in between. [Distinct-value estimation from a sample](http://www.vldb.org/conf/1995/P311.PDF) can do better than a lower bound without information about the distribution of the whole population can it not? (this is not my area at all so apologies if I'm mistaken!)

Comment: Given you know nothing about the distribution, then in what sense do you mean the word "likely"?

Comment: @whuber I'm not sure. I think $A$ and $B$ are essentially random samples without replacement of population $P$. Hence (assuming for simplicity $A$ and $B$ have the same number of elements) if there are say 1000 distinct values, I'd expect most to be represented in $A$ and most in $B$ – for 500 to be only in $A$ and 500 only in $B$ would be exceedingly unlikely.

Comment: I think your intuition is right.